# Outlook Add-in on Exchange 2013: manifest too large

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, exchange-server-2013

We have an Outlook add-in using the office.js API 1.3. One user on Exchange 2013 gets the following error when they try to side-load our add-in:

"This app can't be installed. The manifest file for this app is too large. It must be smaller than 32 KB"

We read somewhere a year ago (can no longer find the link) that this was a known issue with Exchange 2013 which would be fixed "soon" in an update. We cannot find an official statement on this issue from Microsoft.

Was this ever fixed? If so, which update is needed to get the fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange Server 2013 CU14 and above should contain the fix you are looking for.

Comment: In this case I am also getting the same error while installing addin from manifest and my exchange server is 2016 and also the web addins are not seen in client 2016. Any suggessions on this?

Comment: Ajit please create a new question for this issue